# What security protocol can i use to secure a web service (SSL/TLS)?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

I have to secure a web service and the protocols i can use is SSLv2 or SSLv3 or TLSv1.2 or SSLv3 combined with TLSv1.2. I know that SSLv3 is the most secure protocol when it comes to SSL, also the TLSv1.2 is the most secure when it comes to TLS. But the question is what of the above protocols i have to use to secure my web service? Also I would like to know the reason, if there is an answer. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSLv2 is long gone and most clients don't support it any longer because it is insecure. Same thing happened with SSLv3 a few years ago because of the POODLE attack but you still find a considerable number of systems out there supporting SSLv3. TLS 1.0 and 1.1 have their design issues so that it is recommended to no longer to use these but most installations still support these. If you have the free choice of both client and server you should definitely use TLS 1.2 which is currently the latest and considered secure. It will probably replaced as the latest in the next years (or even this year) once TLS 1.3 is finally specified but it will take some time before TLS stacks support this.

Note that the security does not only depend on the protocol version but also on proper choice of cipher, proper certificates and of course the proper validation of the certificate.

Apart from that there is no real difference between SSL and TLS: TLS 1.0 is practically SSL 3.1. Actually the difference between SSL 2.0 and SSL 3.0 is much larger than between SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is not correct, TLS 1.2+ are more secure than SSLv3. SSLv3 is not secure due to recent vulnerabilities like Poodle Attack. You should definitely use TLS 1.2+ to secure your application. A good read is available [here](https://luxsci.com/blog/ssl-versus-tls-whats-the-difference.html).

Comment: SSLv2  (i.e. SSL 2.0) is old and rotten and unrelated to POODLE. You mixed this up with SSLv3 (SSL 3.0) which is affected by POODLE.

Comment: Sorry typing mistake, I meant SSLv3

Answer (score 1):

**TLS** is an upgraded version of the SSL cryptographic protocol and it enables more secure communication on the internet. SSLv3 was deprecated due to POODLE and Other SSL Vulnerabilities.

So, I suggest that you can use **TLS 1.2 protocol** because it was defined in August 2008 and uses today. TLSv1.2 protocol compatible with SSL certificates to provide enhanced communications security to your web service over the internet. [Get more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)